# Python 3 - apply AND operation across 2 boolean values across two matrices at position p

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I have a matrix and a transposed instance of it. I want to apply an `&` operation to determine if both values are `True`. If both values are `True` i will `return True`.

I have Numpy at my disposal, however, I cannot see a function that would let me;

```
m1[i][j] & m2[i][j]
```

for all element pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we've this `numpy` array, you can use `logical_and` alongside with `zip` like this example:

```
import numpy as np

$> a = np.array([[1, 2], [np.nan, 3]]) 
$> np.logical_and(*a)

array([ True,  True])
```

Also:

```
$> a = np.array([[np.nan, 2], [None, 3]]) 
$> np.logical_and(*a)                                                     
array([None, 3], dtype=object)
```

And:

```
$> a = np.array([[False, True], [True, True]]) 
$> np.logical_and(*a) 
array([False,  True])
```

Comment: `np.logical_and` was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written, the value returned (into nowhere) will be the bitwise & operation between m1[i][j] and m2[i][j].  If you want to test if both are true you want to use:

```
m1[i][j] && m2[i][j]
```